# Ubuntu 20.04 won't suspend

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, suspend, system

I always suspend ubuntu with `systemctl suspend`, however since installing an nvidia cuda toolkit 11.3 with another nvidia driver, and installing cuDNN 8.1, I've had issues. When I try to suspend ubuntu, it dims the screen, then an underscore at the top left corenr of the screen, redirects me to a login screen, and when I login, all my previous work is gone, like I had just booted the laptop. Ubuntu has also become slower to boot, usually it booted for 15-20 seconds, now well over a minute. Any ideas on what the issue is?

**EDIT:**

On the advice of @ChanganAuto in the comments, my specs are:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz

GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050

GPU Driver: Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3 (from `nvidia-smi`)

Also, I got my nvidia-cuda-toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local)

Comment: You can and should install both the Nvidia driver and CUDA from the repositories. What you're experiencing now is likely related to a incorrect driver. If you care to edit the question an add the hardware specifications someone may suggest the best driver version (it can be easily check at Nvdia's website BUT drivers shouldn't be installed from Nvidia binaries).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've added the site where I got the nvidia cuda toolkit and my driver version. Also, should I delete the cuda toolkit and install the previous driver and see what happens?

Comment: That you installed it from Nvidia's binaries was a given :) and that's exactly the problem I mentioned in the beginning. Not only this tends to install less than optimal versions it'll also break everything (literally) each time there's a kernel update. Again, always install drivers and CUDA from the repositories and the recommend driver version is 470.xx and that one should have been automatically installed if that option was selected at the OS installation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so I'll need to uninstall the nvidia binaries. On another note, my previous driver version was 470.82.xx, where did you find the recommended driver list for my gpu? I found an advanced search page on the nvidia website that lets you input a few criteria, but all the recommended drivers are 382-391.

Comment: I found it exactly at the Nvidia website > drivers, of course.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I uninstalled the driver and the toolkit and ubuntu suspends properly :)
I'd upvote your comments but I don't have the reputation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think this deserves an answer as is that you could latter upvote/accept and certainly there must be dozens of similar ones already to mark this one as a duplicate of some other, but I won't be chasing them right know. I'm just glad you got it working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced the same problem.Then I got this link.

https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029

Please go through the link, if your nvidia driver isn't 460, then there is a solution for that as well. I've also solved my problem from this comment by
Andrzej Pieńkowski(apienk).

"For me, with nvidia-driver-495, the simple solution was to remove the damaged symlinks from systemd. You most likely have them if you upgraded from nvidia-driver-470, because 470 still included the .service files in /lib/systemd/system/. The files are no longer included in 495 but the postinst script does not remove the symlinks. So, remove them with:"

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.requires/nvidia-resume.service

sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.requires/nvidia-hibernate.service

sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/nvidia-resume.service

sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/nvidia-suspend.service
```

Comment: In my case I temporarily installed nvidia-drivers, then removed. But this files left, preventing suspend/hibernate.